# Looping through text boxes with a number in the variable, to assign data from an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I know this question was probably already asked, however I cant seem to find it.

I have an multi-dimensional array `var values=[["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"],["Jan", "Feb","Mar"]]` I then have a text fields labeled `textField0` and `textField1` and so on.

I would like to create a loop that assigns the array values to the text boxes. Somthing like this (I know this wont work)

```
//x is the current array
var x=0;

var i=0;
while(i<values[x].length){

textField[i].text=values[x][i];

}
```

The user can now change the value of `x` to choose to display the second sub-array of the months, and the text fields will be populated.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want those textfields to show, though? Give an example of the desired outcome, this'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put in `.text`, I edited the Question.I would like `textField0` to display `Sun`, `textField1` to display `Mon` and so forth...

Comment: And how do "Jan" "Feb" and so on factor in to that? Please edit your question with a clear example. (Just asking because I don't get what you're trying to accomplish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `TextField`s in an array as well:

```
var textFields:Array = [textField0, textField1];
```

Then use a loop to iterate over both arrays:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i< textFields.length; ++i)
{
   textFields[i].text =  values[0][i];
}
```